# Tabs not showing when adding them through method

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabs, event-handling, datacontext

I have a datagrid. I want to add Tab when row double click event is rised. When AddTab method is called Tab is added to ObservableCollection, but it doesn't show up on TabControl. Why it doesn't show up? Because there is a wrong DataContext when method called?

```
      <DataGrid  helpers:RowDoubleClickHandler.MethodName="AddTab" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" CanUserResizeRows="True" x:Name="dataGrid1" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridEntries3}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True">
```

AddTab method in ViewModel

```
 public void AddTab()
    {
        Tabs.Add(new TabEntry
        {
            Description = "Tab3",
            DataGridEntries = new ObservableCollection<DataGridEntry>()
            {
                new DataGridEntry()
                {

                }
            }
        });
```

XAML with TabControl

```
<Window x:Class="ProjectZero.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ProjectZero"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ToolBar Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu" Margin="6" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Times New Roman">
                <MenuItem Header="Add Invoice" Command="{Binding AddInvoice}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Invoices List" Command="{Binding AddInvoiceList}" FontFamily="Tahoma" />
            </MenuItem>
            <Menu.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush />
            </Menu.Background>
        </Menu>
        <ToolBar.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF173ADE" Offset="0.431" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF0B1D6F" Offset="0.646" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ToolBar.Background>
    </ToolBar>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplateType1}" TabStripPlacement="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">

    </TabControl>
```

ViewModel for Tabs

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public RelayCommand RelayCommand { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.RelayCommand = new RelayCommand(this);

            Tabs.CollectionChanged += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    foreach (BaseViewModel item in e.NewItems)
                        if (item.MyType == "TabEntry")
                            DataGridEntries3.Add(item as TabEntry);
                }
            };

            var t = (from i in Tabs where i.MyType == "TabEntry" select (TabEntry)i);
            DataGridEntries3 = new ObservableCollection<TabEntry>(t);
        }

        private ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> _tabs;

        public ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> Tabs
        {
            get { return _tabs != null ? _tabs : _tabs = new ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>(); }
            set { _tabs = value; OnPropertyChanged("Tabs"); }
        }

        BaseViewModel _SelectedItem;
        public BaseViewModel SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _SelectedItem; }
            set { _SelectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
        }

private ObservableCollection<TabEntry> _DataGridEntries3;
            public ObservableCollection<TabEntry> DataGridEntries3
            {
        get { return _DataGridEntries3 != null ? _DataGridEntries3 : _DataGridEntries3 = new ObservableCollection<TabEntry>(); }
        set { _DataGridEntries3 = value; OnPropertyChanged("DataGridEntries3"); }
    }

        ICommand _AddInvoice = null;
        ICommand _AddInvoiceList = null;

        public ICommand AddInvoice
        {
            get
            {
                return _AddInvoice != null ? _AddInvoice : _AddInvoice.SetCommand(param =>
                {
                    Tabs.Add(new TabEntry
                    {
                        Description = "Tab3",
                        DataGridEntries = new ObservableCollection<DataGridEntry>()
                {
                    new DataGridEntry()
                    {

                    }
                }
                    });
                });
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddInvoiceList
        {
            get
            {
                return _AddInvoiceList != null ? _AddInvoiceList : _AddInvoiceList.SetCommand(param =>
                {
                    var tab_dc = Tabs.FirstOrDefault(it => it.GetType() == typeof(MainViewModel));
                    if (tab_dc != null)
                    {
                        Tabs.Add(tab_dc);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var new_tab = new MainViewModel();
                        Tabs.Add(new_tab);
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Also here is RowDoubleClick Event Handler

```
public sealed class RowDoubleClickHandler : FrameworkElement
    {
        public RowDoubleClickHandler(DataGrid dataGrid)
        {
            MouseButtonEventHandler handler = (sender, args) =>
            {
                var row = sender as DataGridRow;
                if (row != null && row.IsSelected)
                {
                    var methodName = GetMethodName(dataGrid);

                    var dataContextType = dataGrid.DataContext.GetType();
                    var method = dataContextType.GetMethod(methodName);
                    if (method == null)
                    {
                        throw new MissingMethodException(methodName);
                    }

                    method.Invoke(dataGrid.DataContext, null);
                }
            };

            dataGrid.LoadingRow += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Row.MouseDoubleClick += handler;
            };

            dataGrid.UnloadingRow += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Row.MouseDoubleClick -= handler;
            };
        }

        public static string GetMethodName(DataGrid dataGrid)
        {
            return (string)dataGrid.GetValue(MethodNameProperty);
        }

        public static void SetMethodName(DataGrid dataGrid, string value)
        {
            dataGrid.SetValue(MethodNameProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MethodNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MethodName",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(RowDoubleClickHandler),
            new PropertyMetadata((o, e) =>
            {
                var dataGrid = o as DataGrid;
                if (dataGrid != null)
                {
                    new RowDoubleClickHandler(dataGrid);
                }
            }));
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the XAML for your TabControl & the VM code for how Tabs is defined?

Comment: Sorry man, this code is far too messy for me to follow. I think you will just have to do some old-fashion debugging. Stick a breakpoint on AddTab() and see if it is hit. I can't see where it is getting called from your code or how your row double click helper is implemented. I think, as soon as you start having collections of this named "Tab" in your VM, then your code is starting to not be MVVM anymore.

Comment: Change ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplateType1}" to ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateType1}" in your TabControl.

Comment: AnjumSKhan, that didn't help. I added a TabControl to my view with datagrid, I copy pasted it from my MainView where the main Tabcontol is located. Result: new Tab is added on that TabControl when row double click event rised, but on the MainView's TabControl Tab is not showing. I think I messed with MainView. Will look further, welcome to any suggestions, including about code organization, since I'm new to MVVM and programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

A few tips, since you asked in your comment:

This:

```
    private ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> _tabs;

    public ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> Tabs
    {
        get { return _tabs != null ? _tabs : _tabs = new ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>(); }
        set { _tabs = value; OnPropertyChanged("Tabs"); }
    }
```

Could be rewritten a lot cleaner as:

```
public ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> Tabs { get; private set; }
```

With this added to your constructor:

```
Tabs = new ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>();
```

This is a consistent theme in your code. Basically, don't make modifications in your property getters/setters unless you really really need to. And in your case, all it is doing is complicating things.

It is especially confusing when you have a getter that then will add a tab to your collection of tabs when first invoked. That is very difficult to follow programmatically. Just do your initialization in your constructor like everyone else does :)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. Question about views and viewmodels. Each view must have its own viewmodel (where ObservableCollection is located) or I can put two different ObservableCollection's into one viewmodel?

Comment: @MrgGek You don't need to have a different VM per View. The primary concern should always be (and this goes for all software you write) what is clear and clean. Sometimes you might have a VM which maps to a class in your Model, and have multiple different views of that VM. Like a condensed view, and an expanded detailed view. The VM is there to help the view, but it shouldn't know about the view. You should be able to completely replace the view with something different without much(or any?) changes to your VM.